# Turning a database into a physical view using wpf xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, database, xaml, datagrid

So, I'm trying to connect to my database in a DataGrid view

In `DatabaseDisplay.xaml.cs`:

```
 DataBaseConnection _dbView;
    DataSet _dataSet;
    DataRow _data;

    public DatabaseDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new DataBaseConnection();
    }
```

In `DataBaseConnection.cs`:

```
class DataBaseConnection
{
    private string _dbConnector;

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection _connectionToDb;

    private System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter _dataAdapter;

    public DataBaseConnection(string dbConnector)
    {
        this._dbConnector = dbConnector;
    }

    // Get the data set generated by the sqlStatement
    public DataSet GetDataSet(string sqlStatement)
    {
        _dataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, _connectionToDb);

        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        _dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        return dataSet;
    }
    public void AddValues()
    {
        OpenConnection();
        _dbConnector.Insert(1, "abc");
    }
}
```

I am trying to connect to my database, and then populate the values in `DataBaseDisplay.xaml` which is pretty much a `DataGrid` and a Binding - nothing too fancy. 
My issue is that when I try and pull `DataContext = new DataBaseConnection();` it is giving me the error of: `there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'dbConnector' of 'DataBaseConnection.DataBaseConnection'`

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Error is given cause your `DataBaseConnection` constructor requires `dbConnector` string parameter and you don't pass it in `DataBaseDisplay` constructor.